# Elm: signal for two keyboard keys together?

Tags: elm

How would one create a signal for <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> or any other pair of keys in Elm?

Is there a built-in way for doing this, or do I have to create something myself?

I'm very new to Elm, so any additional explanation is always welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
Signal.map2 (&&) Keyboard.alt (Keyboard.isDown <| Char.toCode 'O')
```

This creates a single `Signal Bool` that's true when both are down, otherwise false.

Comment: If you are interested in Elm Signal I explained [here](https://git.io/elm-signal)

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a built-in way in elm to handle keyboard inputs

The module is keyboard.elm

From my understanding to be able to use this you have to

```
import keyboard
import Signal exposing ((<~))
```

The *keysDown* function creates a signal which informs what keys are currently being pressed

```
import Keyboard
import Signal exposing ((<~))
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)


main = show <~ Keyboard.keysDown
```

The *isDown* function takes a key code as its argument and returns a boolean signal indicating whether the given key is currently being pressed. There are also helper functions defined in terms of *isDown* for certain special keys: *shift*, *ctrl*, *space* and *enter*.

```
import Char
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Keyboard
import Signal exposing ((<~))


main = show <~ Keyboard.isDown (Char.toCode 'A')
```

Comment: Thanks! Though I by now figured it out myself. This also doesn't explain how to combine multiple presses into a single one.

Comment: Yeah no problem. I'm new to stackoverflow myself. I'm glad to help... Errr well sort of

Comment: Elm 0.16 was just released yesterday and the `<~` operator was removed from the core libraries version that corresponds to that release. Perhaps it's a good idea to change your code snippets to use `Signal.map`.

Comment: @TheOddler if you figured it out yourself, can you submit your own answer?

Comment: @Apanatshka they did see below