# Elm keyboard combination shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, elm

In my Elm program I would like to have some keyboard shortcuts.

I have a shortcut `d` which does what I want, however, I want the key combination to be `alt+d`.

```
StartApp.start { 
    init = (emptyModel, Effects.none),
    view   = view, 
    update = update,
    inputs = [ Signal.map forwardKey Keyboard.presses]
    }

forwardKey : Int -> Action    
forwardKey keyCode =
  case (Char.fromCode keyCode) of
    'd' -> Add
    _ -> NoOp
```

I noticed that there is a keyboard.alt signal that returns `Signal Bool` to check if alt is pressed or not.

How can I apply change the shortcut from `d` to `alt+d` by using this signal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[See this answer to the same underlying question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833483/34409).

Note that it's going to be difficult to impossible to capture Alt-D since that's a common key combination used by browsers. For example, Chrome shifts focus to the address bar when you press Alt-D. For this reason, I'll revert to the example above and use Alt-0 as the chord here:

You can use `map2` to create a new Boolean signal that tells if your key combination is pressed. We'll create a new signal called `chordPressed` like so:

```elm
chordPressed : Signal Bool
chordPressed =
  Signal.map2 (&&) Keyboard.alt (Keyboard.isDown <| Char.toCode '0')
```

Now, we need to convert that signal to an Action before we can pass it into the `inputs` list.

```elm
chordToAction : Signal Action
chordToAction =
  let
    toAction b =
      case b of
        True -> Add
        False -> NoOp
  in
    Signal.dropRepeats
      <| Signal.map toAction chordPressed
```

Now, you can pass `chordToAction` into the `inputs` list. Again, you might want to choose a key-chord that isn't going to be first caught by the browser, like Alt-D will.

```elm
inputs = [ chordToAction ]
```

Comment: Could you also tell me how I have to use it? Should I put it in the inputs array? How can I access the new boolean in my forwardKey method? If forwardKey method not necesarry, how can I determine the action to my keyboard combination? Sorry for the trouble... and thanks!

Comment: @Thibault: I've expanded the example to show a mapping from that original boolean signal to one of your Actions.